# Google Apps Script complains about "strict" but there's no "use strict" in the sources. How can this be?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm developing a Google Sheets application using Google Apps Script. I am using TypeScript, ts2gas and VSCode on a Windows 10 machine.

None of the source specifies "use strict" in any form, however I keep getting an error message that says,

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

The full error log from the `Executions` page reads:

```
May 7, 2020, 1:10:00 PM Error   TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at CalleeName(CommonFunctions/01_Kernel:3:14)
    at Toast(CommonFunctions/01_Kernel:51:16)
    at CartridgeSpecified_ConvertSheetToXml(CommonFunctions/01_Kernel_CartridgeSpecified:24:5)
    at SaveButton(03_Sheet_DataEntry:60:20)
```

I do use callee and arguments, and because I do use them I avoid strict mode completely. Nevertheless, the interpreter seems to be convinced that I'm using it.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: How to reproduce?

Comment: Tricky. Intermittent error, probably. I've commented out the functions that use the offending functions and I'll just have to not use them. It's only for a function that gets the execution context for the sake of debugging

Comment: Even without "use-strict", some objects(for eg, `class`es) always run in strict mode.

Comment: Pity a comment can't be an answer

Comment: What? If the comment solved the issue, I'll add a answer. Given the lack of [mcve], I can't add a answer unless I'm sure it fixed the issue.